# Prevent 504 gateway timeout on overpass api with piped node request

Tags: json, node.js, request, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I use following code for a OpenStreetMap-query (overpass-API). It works fine on smaller querys but on a bigger one, which takes around 10 min, it generates only a 504 gateway timeout response.

**code:**

```
var reqStr = "http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=...

console.time("query");
var stream = request(reqStr,{timeout: 3600000}).on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err)
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('resultExport.json'));
stream.on('finish', function () {
    console.timeEnd("query");
});
```

**response (resultExport.json):**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Gateway Time-out</h1>
<p>The gateway did not receive a timely response
from the upstream server or application.</p>
</body></html>
```

The query command has a *[timeout:3600]* (seconds) and the request got *{timeout: 3600000}* (milliseconds). What else can i do prevent the timeout and get a proper response? I am a bit confused where this is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known issue, which hasn't been addressed/fixed yet on the Overpass API server.

See this Github issue for details: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/220

Comment: So there is no way to make querys, which take longer than a few minutes?

Comment: Well, yes, that's why I created that ticket on Github. If your query takes a lot of time to produce first results, you will run into the timeout. If your query starts to produce some data pretty early and just continuous to return data, you should be fine. Maybe your bbox is too large or your query too complex? Impossible to tell, as you didn't provide your query.